# Node Express, simplify route callback from mongoose

Tags: node.js, express

Using Express, how can I simplify this code, in particular the service callback function I pass which uses the res variable which means I can't declare that function beforehand.

```
app.post('/user', function(req, res) {
    service.create(req.body, function(err, obj) {
      if (err) {
        res.send(500);
      } else {
        res.send(obj);
      }
    });
  });

  app.put('/user/:id', function(req, res) {
    service.update(req.params.id, req.body, function(err, obj) {
      if (err) {
        res.send(500);
      } else {
        res.send(obj);
      }
    });
  });

  app.delete('/user/:id', function(req, res) {
    service.delete(req.params.id, function(err, obj) {
      if (err) {
        res.send(500);
      } else {
        res.send(obj);
      }
    });
  });

  app.get('/user/:id', function(req, res) {
    service.read(req.params.id, function(err, obj) {
      if (err) {
        res.send(500);
      } else {
        res.send(obj);
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a function which returns anonymous function which handles the mongoose models but still has access to response object through closure.

```
var serviceCallback = function(response){
   return function(err, obj){
      if (err) {
        response.send(500);
      } else {
        response.send(obj);
      }
    }
}

app.post('/user', function(req, res) {
    service.create(req.body, serviceCallback(res));
}
app.put('/user/:id', function(req, res) {
    service.update(req.params.id, req.body, serviceCallback(res));
}
app.delete('/user/:id', function(req, res) {
    service.delete(req.params.id, serviceCallback(res));
}
app.get('/user/:id', function(req, res) {
    service.read(req.params.id, serviceCallback(res));
}
```

Comment: +1, I've edited my answer to point to this one. Didn't think to do that myself ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Sriharsha's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19039285/586621) for how you can manage the callbacks.

---

If you didn't want to do that for some reason, your logic is simple & it can be shortened into a simple ternary operator:

```
res.send(err ? 500 : obj);
```

e.g.

```
app.post('/user', function(req, res) {
  service.create(req.body, function(err, obj) { res.send(err ? 500 : obj); });
});
```